# Ordered tests created in VS2015 won't open in VS2017

Tags: coded-ui-tests, visual-studio-2017

I have a lot of Ordered tests in my Coded UI Test project in VS2015. I have upgraded to VS2017 and added the **Individual Components** -> ***Coded UI Test*** and ***Testing tool core features***.

My solution opens, builds and runs. I can record new tests etc.

The only thing I cannot do is open the Ordered tests as they normally open (in Open With, it's the "Ordered Test Editor (Default)"). I can open them in the "XML (Text) Editor" but you can't add newly recorded tests to your ordered test there.

The error is "***The operation could not be completed***". That's the whole message and it doesn't tell me much. Am I missing a component and if so what?

I can create new ordered tests, the problem is simply adding to and editing my existing ordered tests.

As a work around I tried making a new ordered test, open it in XML and copy the whole `<TestLinks>` section from my old ordered test (the VS2015 one). This half works, the ordered test will open but it then doesn't show the tests that I just copied into it in XML. I do this all the time in VS2015 and it works fine but not in VS2017.

What's going on with the ordered tests compatibility and how do I open my VS 2015 ordered tests in the standard Ordered Test Editor in 2017?

Answer (score 2):

We encountered this issue as well, and you don't actually have to delete all the existing tests and re-add them.

The issue is because the previous `.orderedtests` TestLinks contained an attribute

```
type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
```

Which includes an explicit reference to a specific version for the element. This version was apparently updated in VS2017, which causes VS to fail to load it properly (as it's not smart enough to recognize the version mismatch). Simply removing the `Version=14.0.0.0,` is enough to fix it (make sure to replace all lines). This attribute should become

```
type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel,   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

To change it you'll need to open it as XML as the other answer explained, or open it in a text editor. Then do a find and replace.

The project still builds successfully on our VS2015 build server, so I would hope this change is backwards compatible as well.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, and here's what I did to resolve it:

1. Right-click on the ordered test, select "Open With", select "XML
   (Text) Editor", then click OK.
2. Highlight all of your existing  entries and delete them. 
   Save the file.
3. Re-open the file in the Ordered Test Editor.  (Right-click and
   select "Open With...Ordered Test Editor (default)" if you have to)
4. Re-add the existing test steps, and save again.

This worked for me.  I hope it works for you!